# Modifying my methods to use PreparedStatement Objects instead of Statement Objects

Tags: java, sql, api, jdbc, prepared-statement

How do I modify this code to take in PreparedStatement Objects (instead of Statement Objects)?

```
    package com.cs330;
    import javax.ws.rs.*;
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.ResultSet;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import java.sql.Statement;

    @Path("ws2")
    public class IngredientServices 
     @Path("/ingredients")
     @GET
     @Produces("text/plain")
     public String getIngredients() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {

     String connectStr="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/fooddb";
     //database username

     String username="root";
     //database password

     String password="csci330pass";
     /* The driver is the Java class used for accessing
      * a particular database. You must download this from
      * the database vendor.
      */

     String driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
     Class.forName(driver);
     //Creates a connection object for your database

     Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectStr, username, password);
     /* Creates a statement object to be executed on
      * the attached database.
      */

     Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
     /* Executes a database query and returns the results
      * as a ResultSet object.
      */

     ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT id, name, category FROM ingredient");
     /* This snippet shows how to parse a ResultSet object.
      * Basically, you loop through the object sort of like
      * a linkedlist, and use the getX methods to get data
      * from the current row. Each time you call rs.next()
      * it advances to the next row returned.
      * The result variable is just used to compile all the
      * data into one string.
      */

      String result = "";
      while (rs.next()) 
      {
      int theId = rs.getInt("id");
       String theName = rs.getString("name");
       String theCategory = rs.getString("category");
       result += "id: "+theId+ " , name: "+theName + "("+theCategory+")" + "\n" + "\n";
       }
        return result;
      }//END 

    @Path("/ingredients/{id}")
     @GET
     @Produces("text/plain")
     public String getIngredientById(@PathParam("id") String theId) 
     throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
     int intId = 0;
     try 
     {
      intId = Integer.parseInt(theId);
     }
     catch (NumberFormatException FAIL) 
     {
      intId = 1;
     }//Obtaining an ingredient from the database

     String connectStr="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/fooddb";
     String username="root";
     String password="csci330pass";
     String driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
     Class.forName(driver);
     Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectStr, username, password);
     Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
     ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT id, name, category FROM ingredient 
     WHERE id=" +intId);

     String result = "";
     while (rs.next()) 
     {
      int theId2 = rs.getInt("id");
      String theName2 = rs.getString("name");
      String theCategory = rs.getString("category");
      result += "id: "+theId2+ " , name: "+theName2 + "("+theCategory+")" + "\n" + "\n";
     }
      return result;
    }//END METHOD

    @Path("/ingredients/name")
    @GET
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String getIngredientByName(@QueryParam("name") String theName) 
    throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException
    {
     //Obtaining an ingredient from the database
     String connectStr="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/fooddb";
     String username="root";
     String password="csci330pass";
     String driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
     Class.forName(driver);
     Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectStr, username, password);
     Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
     ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT id, name, category FROM ingredient WHERE 
     name='" + theName + "'");

     String result = "";
     while (rs.next()) 
     {
      int theId3 = rs.getInt("id");
      String theName3 = rs.getString("name");
      String theCategory = rs.getString("category");
      result += "id: "+theId3+ " , name: "+theName3 + "("+theCategory+")" + "\n" + "\n";
     }
      return result;
     }//END METHOD
    }//END CODE
```

I know for a fact that it is not as simple as just changing the object variable from Statement to PreparedStatement... That's why I'm asking for some suggestions here. Thank You.

Comment: Have a look at this, http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparestatement-example-select-list-of-the-records/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few steps:

1. Change the type from `Statement` to `PreparedStatement`.
2. Store your queries in `String` variables. Any place where you should use a dynamic value (e.g. the places where you concatenate a `String`) will be parameters for your query, replace these variables by `?`.
3. Create the `PreparedStatement` by using `Connection#prepareStatement` rather than using `Connection.createStatement`.
4. Set the parameters in your `PreparedStatement` by using `setXxx` methods.
5. Execute the statement by using `executeQuery` method.

An example is covered in [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) javadoc.

This is how you can change `getIngredientById` method by following steps above:

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectStr, username, password);
//from "SELECT id, name, category FROM ingredient WHERE id=" + intId
//check the usage of ? instead of intId
String sql = "SELECT id, name, category FROM ingredient WHERE id = ?";
PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
//setting variable in PreparedStatement
pstmt.setInt(1, intId);
ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
String result = "";
while (rs.next()) {
    //consume the data...
}
```

This is how you can change `getIngredientByName` method by following steps above:

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectStr, username, password);
//? don't need you to escape it by using ' around
//? is equals to the parameter, this is why using PreparedStatement is more safe
//it will help you to avoid SQL Injection attacks
String sql = "SELECT id, name, category FROM ingredient WHERE name = ?";
PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
pstmt.setString(1, theName);
ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
String result = "";
while (rs.next()) {
    //consume the data...
}
```

Do similar for the necessary methods in your project.

Comment: I won't have to modify the ToString parts, will I? Or do I leave those be? Either way, thank you for some leeway to what's killing me here.

Comment: @user2891351 if you're talking about the `ResultSet` code, no there's nothing to change. Also, I would recommend using `StringBuilder` rather than string concatenation to consume the data of the query.

Comment: I'm sorry to ask: how would I go about typing the code for getIngredientbyName??? I typed it up myself, but it clearly isn't right, because I keep getting only the very first result of the index, even when I type in full names of other valid results contianed within the MySQL database program...

Comment: That's exactly it... Either way, thank you for that - so in regards to why this might not work on my webserver, the problem might be somewhere else after all. This changes everything.